# Не хочет выводится результат читания с масива

Tags: c++, массивы

У меня есть масив  в нем я функцией ищу  символ который  больше всех встречается.  Но если я  задам в масив максимальный елемент 200 все ок работаете. а если 20000  то уже не  хочет выводить результат. Неужели  с  большимы  масивами не можна работать?

```
const int max_elem = 20000;
char *array1 = new char(max_elem); // и рандомно  заполняю массив. Я  этот код не скидывал, он правильно работает
char  find = findCharacter(array1, max_elem); // тут я своей функцией ищу символ, она правильно работает
```

Comment: Почитайте как сделать [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

Для задания массива нужно использовать квадратные скобки:

```
char *array1 = new char[max_elem];
```

При использовании круглых скобок вы создаете *один* символ char с указанным в скобках значением.